# Android GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Is it possible add LinearLayout on GLSurfaceView?
How to overlay LinearLayout over a GLSurfaceView?
maybe GLSurfaceView is Game playground and LinearLayout is menubar~

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a FrameLayout. Have the GLSurfaceView as the first view in the FrameLayout, then add the LinearLayout second. This will put the linearLayout and anything in it over the top of the GLSurfaceView:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/graphics_frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/graphics_glsurfaceview1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Edit: Now with picture:

[image: Android Framelayout for games. Check out ma ms paint skillz]

Comment: I have done essentially this with JAVA instead of xml but the glSurfaceView has an inherent onDraw Method and it appears that this method always brings the glSurface back to the top..

Comment: How are you using glSurfaceView? Are you extending it or attaching a Renderer?

Comment: Extending it and doing relview.addview(glView);

Comment: I use GLSurfaceView.Renderer. I forgot how to do it with just extending GLSurfaceView :P. Maybe post as a separate question if you haven't already, along with the code?

Comment: I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596778/how-to-build-a-gui-hud-over-top-a-glsurfaceview-in-android

Comment: @JamesCoote You seem to have great knowledge on these type of situations with OpenGL. Do you think you could help me on this posting?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749898/android-opengl-glsurfaceview-using-gridview-surface