# how to build a GUI/HUD over top a glSurfaceView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, glsurfaceview

I have an `glSurfaceView` that looks like this:

```
public class GLLayer extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Renderer {

    private Context context;

    private Circle cRing;
    private CompassNeedle cNeedle;

    private MarkerNorth mNorth;
    private MarkerEast mEast;
    private MarkerSouth mSouth;
    private MarkerWest mWest;
    private MarkerSouthWest mSWest;
    private MarkerSouthEast mSEast;
    private MarkerNorthWest mNWest;
    private MarkerNorthEast mNEast;
    private MarkerWest mGod;
    private MarkerCustom userTag;
    ArrayList <MarkerCustom> locationTags;

    private PhoneOrientation phoneOri;
    private boolean randomSelection[][][]=new boolean[10][10][10];
    ArrayList<double[]> tags = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    double tempOr[] = new double[3];
    ARLaunch _parent;

    RelativeLayout rel;

    public GLLayer(Context context, int orientation, ArrayList<MarkerCustom> custMarkers,ARLaunch parent) {
        super(context);

        locationTags = custMarkers;
        _parent = parent;

        this.context = context;

        this.mGod = new MarkerWest();
        this.cRing = new Circle();
        this.cNeedle = new CompassNeedle();

        this.mNorth = new MarkerNorth();
        this.mEast = new MarkerEast();
        this.mSouth = new MarkerSouth();
        this.mWest = new MarkerWest();

        this.mSWest = new MarkerSouthWest();
        this.mSEast = new MarkerSouthEast();
        this.mNWest = new MarkerNorthWest();
        this.mNEast = new MarkerNorthEast();

        phoneOri=new PhoneOrientation(context); // sensor manager and interpreter

        // settings for translucent glView
        this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        // set render to inline 
        this.setRenderer(this);

        phoneOri.start(context, orientation);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Reset the Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        float floatMat[]=phoneOri.getMatrix();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);


        gl.glLoadMatrixf(floatMat, 1);
        //ArrayList<Square[]> squares = new ArrayList<Square[]>();


        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0,0,-10.0f);
        cNeedle.draw(gl);
        gl.glLoadMatrixf(floatMat,0);

        gl.glTranslatef(0,0,10.0f);
        cRing.draw(gl);


        //Draw South
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,-150.0f,-10.0f);
        mSouth.draw(gl); 

        //Draw West
        gl.glTranslatef(-150.0f,150.0f,0.0f);
        mWest.draw(gl);

        //DrawNorth
        gl.glTranslatef(150.0f,150.0f,0.0f);
        mNorth.draw(gl); 

        //DrawEast
        gl.glTranslatef(150.0f,-150.0f,0.0f);
        mEast.draw(gl);

        //SW
        gl.glTranslatef(-225.0f, -75.0f, 0.0f);
        mSWest.draw(gl);

        // NW
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,150.f,0);
        mNWest.draw(gl);

        gl.glTranslatef(150.0f, 0f, 0f);
        mNEast.draw(gl);

        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,-150.0f,0.0f);
        mSEast.draw(gl);



         gl.glPushMatrix();


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
      if(height == 0) {                    //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
        }
        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix
                                                //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window

        //gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 100);
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 35.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 5.0f, 200.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 1.0f, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) {
        // Load the texture for the square
        //square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        for(int i=0;i<locationTags.size();i++){
            userTag=locationTags.get(i);
            userTag.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
            //Figure out how to load textures for each
        }
        cRing.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        cNeedle.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mNorth.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mEast.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mSouth.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mWest.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mSWest.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mNWest.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mSEast.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        mNEast.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //Black Background
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

        //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
        //gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

In my main Activity I am adding it to the view like so:

```
    setContentView(frame);

                frame.addView(camPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                frame.addView(glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                frame.addView(lin);
                lin.addView(rel);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pNav = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            pNav.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,1);
            pNav.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            pNav.rightMargin = 20;


            rel.addView(imageView,pNav);
            lin.bringToFront();
            ;


            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODOn Auto-generated method stub
                    glView.newTag();

                }
            });
```

Problem is the `glSurfaceView` appears at the very top level, covering the `imageView` but still allowing the user to click on the `imageView`.  How can i get the ImageView to stay at the top of the View like a HUD or GUI

Comment: lin should be at the top of the frameview stack anyway, so you should not need to call `bringToFront()`. Try commenting out that line and the line adding the imageview to rel, and instead add a simple text view to lin, just to make sure it isn't something like the image not loading

Comment: I know the image is loading as I can still see it.. its just underneath.  Also I just added the bring to front just to reinforce.. shouldn't be needed. Again I think its the on draw method of the glsurface bringing it to the front..

Comment: Well `onDraw` is an inherited method from View, whilst `onDrawFrame` is an interface method from `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. If you comment out all your code from `onDrawFrame`, you can see which one is the real cause of the problem

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake I meant onDrawFrame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After almost a year I came back to this and found the following solution to work like a charm..  I know many have battled with this same issue so I thought I'd share to save anyone the aggravation I endured.

Simple: before adding my views to the frame layout I set the glView's zOrderMediaOverlay to TRUE  like so:

```
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
rel.addView(camPreview, camParams);
rel.addView(glView, glParams);
rel.addView(imageView, imageParams);
```